# Why does Selenium and Chrome crash intermittently on Raspberry Pi (Buster)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3

I’m having a terrible time getting Selenium and Chrome to run reliably on my Raspberry Pi (Buster) running headless to scrape a website. I’m using a Pi 3 Model B, Rev 1.2 and running Selenium 3.141.0 and Chrome & chromedriver version 74.0.3729.157.

The code below runs fine for up to a few hours (called by cron every 15 minutes), collecting data, saving it locally, and using request to post it to an external website. But within 3 – 4 hours, I get one of these errors:

`(<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>, WebDriverException()'
'(<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException()'
'(<type 'exceptions.NameError'>, NameError("name 'display' is not defined",)`

Even with my attempt to catch the exception, the error causes the Pi to totally freeze up, which requires a power reset.

Can anyone see any errors in how I’ve setup selenium and chrome in my code? Or recommend improvements? (this is my first attempt with Selenium and I've used code from a bunch of online examples and tutorials.)

Is Chrome 74 supported by Raspbian buster?  I’ve seen some suggestions that Chromium support for ARM was officially dropped since v65, but I haven't seen an official announcement.
Should I give up on Chrome and try Firefox?

````
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Designed as a once-thru program to be called by cron every 15 minutes

import time
from datetime import datetime, date
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import requests
import sys

try:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200))
    display.start()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)

    # Navigate to target website
    driver.get('https://auth.tesla.com/login')

    # Sign in ...
    # Navigate to desired pages ...
    # scrape data, save to local files, use request to post to external website ...


except:    # catches ALL errors and writes them to file
    error_msg = sys.exc_info()
    with open(error_msg_file_name, "a") as error_file:
        error_file.write('\n')
        error_file.write(str((datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))))
        error_file.write(', ')
        error_file.write(str(error_msg))
        error_file.write('\n')

finally:      #this will always be executed
    driver.quit() # quit webdriver and cleanup before exiting```
````